# Error in java servlet on stmt.executeUpdate

Tags: java, jdbc, compiler-errors

This is my code:

```
String[] teams = {"Blue Team", "Red Team", "Yellow Team", "Green Team", "Orange Team"};
            int count = 0, team = 0;
            String selectSQL = "select * from students"; // rand and distinct
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);
            // Retrieve the results
            while(rs1.next()){
                if(count==3){
                    team++;
                    count = 0;
                }
            stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into "teams[team]" values ('"+rs1.getString("studentno")+"', '"+rs1.getString("firstname")+"', '"+rs1.getString("surname")+"', '"+rs1.getString("degreecode")+"', '"+rs1.getString("dob")+"')");
            }
```

I get an error on stmt.executeUpdate. This is the error:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error on token "]", AssignmentOperator expected after this token
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token

    CreateTheTeams.doGet(CreateTheTeams.java:69)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

How is possible to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your Java source file, this has nothing to do with Servlet directly.

Notice in this part of your code:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into "teams[team]" values ('"+ // more code here
```

There is no `+` concatenanting the `"Insert into "`, `teams[team]` and `" values ('"`. To begin fixing your problems, change that part into:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into "+teams[team]+" values ('"+ // more code here
//                               ^           ^
```

From the error message, you can figure that out by yourself:

`java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:` states that your file couldn't even be compiled.

But the best part:

```
CreateTheTeams.doGet(CreateTheTeams.java:69)
```

Tells you where it is finding the error: at line **69** of the **CreateTheTeams.java** file. Next time you see something like that, get to that line and reread carefully, this may save you some time.

Comment: This only solves the compilation problem but still left open the `Statement` usage for two different operations.

Comment: Indeed. Actually I didn't go into the semantics of the code at all. I expect the `+` is a fix to just the beginning of his problems (the one stated in the question). The closed `ResultSet`, due to the reuse of the `Statement`, should yield an `Exception` right away, with lines pointed out (I hoped to help in this). The immediate solution for the specific problem would be to use `conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("Insert into "+teams[team]+...`, but the code seems to have much more problems (a table named `"Blue Team"`?), that's why I didn't tackle all the possibilities before a feedback.

Comment: By reading OP's comments in code, seems that at final stage he/she needs to fill each team with different students.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! Yeah "Blue Team" is a university assignment :)) !

Comment: The name is Ok. I meant the space in the table's name. It's not that it can't exist, but usually it requires escaping, like `INSERT INTO \`Blue Team\` VALUES ...`. Anyway, using spaces in there is bad, error prone, practice.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? If so, you should accept (check the green tick) an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors:

1. Compilation error, since you have an invalid `String`.
2. Using a same `Statement` for two different operations. When performing the second operation, the `ResultSet` of the already executed operation will be lost.

To solve each one:

1. This is not a valid String:

   ```
   "Insert into "teams[team]" values ('"+rs1.getString("studentno")+"', '"+rs1.getString("firstname")+"', '"+rs1.getString("surname")+"', '"+rs1.getString("degreecode")+"', '"+rs1.getString("dob")+"')"
   ```

   You need to concatenate the `String`s accordingly:

   ```
   //note the usage of + signs between teams[team]
   "Insert into " + teams[team] + " values ('" + rs1.getString("studentno") +
       "', '"+ rs1.getString("firstname") + "', '" + rs1.getString("surname")+
       "', '" + rs1.getString("degreecode") + "', '" + rs1.getString("dob")+ "')"
   ```
2. It would be better using a new `Statement` for this:

   ```
   String insertSql = "Insert into " + teams[team] + " values ('" + rs1.getString("studentno") +
       "', '"+ rs1.getString("firstname") + "', '" + rs1.getString("surname")+
       "', '" + rs1.getString("degreecode") + "', '" + rs1.getString("dob")+ "')";
   Statement stmtInsert = connection.createStatement(insertSql);
   stmtInsert.executeUpdate();
   ```

   But this will be even better if you use a `PreparedStatement` to avoid SQL Injection. To do this, change the code to:

   ```
   String insertSql = "Insert into " + teams[team] + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
   PreparedStatement pstmtInsert = connection.prepareStatement(insertSql);
   pstmt.setParameter(1, rs1.getString("studentno"));
   pstmt.setParameter(2, rs1.getString("firstname"));
   pstmt.setParameter(3, rs1.getString("surname"));
   pstmt.setParameter(4, rs1.getString("degreecode"));
   pstmt.setParameter(5, rs1.getString("dob"));
   pstmtInsert.executeUpdate();
   pstmtInsert.close();
   ```

Also, not an error but seems that you never update `count` variable, so `if(count==3)` will never occur. To fix it, add a `count++` after executing your DML insert operation.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
    stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into "teams[team]" values ('"+rs1.getString("studentno")+"', '"+rs1.getString("firstname")+"', '"+rs1.getString("surname")+"', '"+rs1.getString("degreecode")+"', '"+rs1.getString("dob")+"')");
```

has a compilation error. You need to add + to concatenate the strings in the statement:

```
        stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into "+teams[team]+" values ('"+rs1.getString("studentno")+"', '"+rs1.getString("firstname")+"', '"+rs1.getString("surname")+"', '"+rs1.getString("degreecode")+"', '"+rs1.getString("dob")+"')");
```